# How to mitigate floating point error in recursive DSP calculations

Tags: python, linear-prediction, floating-point

I have implemented a modified linear prediction coding function like this:

```
def modified_lpc_process(s: NDArray, p: int, fs: int) -> NDArray:
a = lpc_coefficients(s, p)
a_hat = modified_pole_coeffs(a, fs=fs)
# a_hat = a # debug line
s_hat = numpy.zeros(len(s))

for n, sn in enumerate(s):
    as_accum = 0
    for k in range(len(a)):
        if n - 1 - k < 0:
            break
        as_accum += a[k] * s[n - 1 - k]
    un = sn + as_accum

    as_hat_accum = 0
    for k in range(len(a_hat)):
        if n - 1 - k < 0:
            break
        as_hat_accum += a_hat[k] * s_hat[n - 1 - k]

    s_hat[n] = -as_hat_accum + un
    round(s_hat[n], 8)

return s_hat
```

Which essentially implements the maths here:

\begin{align}
u_n &= s_n + \sum_{k=1}^p a_k s_{n-k}\\
\hat{s}_n &= - \sum_{k=1}^p \hat{a}_k \hat{s}_{n-k} + u_n
\end{align}

I have noticed that the floating point error in this operation quickly blows up and I end up with sample values too large. In an effort to debug, I've set the modified pole coefficients `a_hat` to be the same with `a`, expecting to get the same value for `s_hat` and `s`; but the same issue is still there. I've also just realised that in floating point, adding a number and subtracting the same number you end up with slightly different results, which in recursive applications like this can accumulate to large differences.

I wonder what the best practice is in this case to mitigate this error accumulation?

Comment: Do you know where your poles and zeros are?  And may I modify the question to use more common (dare I say "standard") notation in the DSP lit?  It's quite likely that people will suggest factoring your IIR filter into 2nd-order stages.  Otherwise, if your floating-point wordsize is decent and your poles are not directly on (or outside) the unit circle, there shouldn't be a nasty rounding error accumulation.

Comment: Looking at this a second time, I noticed that this is about Linear Predictive Coding.  It might be that your LPC filter is unstable.  How long is it? `len(s)`?

Comment: So my filter length len(a) currently is 10, and I’ve made sure the poles are inside the unit circle by nudging the ones outside to have a magnitude of 0.95. The length of s is the current buffer so right now it is 240; but I’ve tried with smaller sizes and it still blows up. I’ll have a double check on my logic there for pole calculation

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it. It is indeed because of having unstable poles, but I was only looking at each individual transfer function instead of the overall transfer function.

In lpc the individual transfer functions are in the form of $$\frac{1}{1-\sum_{k=1}^{p}a_kz^{-k}}$$
However the overall transfer in my case, combining both lines of equations for $u_n$ and $\hat{s}_n$ becomes:
$$
\frac{1+\sum_{k=1}^{p}a_kz^{-k}}{1+\sum_{k=1}^{p}\hat{a}_kz^{-k}}
$$

So I needed to correct the poles for this denominator, which has a different sign for the sum term than the general lpc transfer function.

I believe this is because I am using the original signal as input, as opposed to traditional lpc which uses a generated excitation, therefore the transfer function has a different sign.